# How can I easily view the Camera or Viewport position?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

How can I easily find out the current X,Y,Z position of the viewport camera, and/or edit them numerically? Not necessarily a camera object, just the point I'm currently viewing the scene from.

It would be useful if I want to check I'm viewing it from human head height, for example.

Comment: There is also the add-on "[Stored View](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/3d_view/stored_views.html)" that ships with Blender. It lets you create a camera from the current view. Then you can see there the transformation settings.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following script. When you execute it in the [`Text Editor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/text_editor.html), it will set the [`3D Cursor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html) at the center of the position of your current view in the 3D Viewport. Notice that after I execute the script, I slightly zoom out so you can see the position of the 3D Cursor where previously the view of 3D Viewport was located at.

[image]

```
import bpy

area = next(area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
current_location = area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation
print("Location of Current View:", current_location)
bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = current_location
```